# AngularJS Protractor; cannot find element

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I tried to get an element and check if it's displayed. I get this error:
    Unable to find element with css selector 'logo'

This is my code:

```
describe("Homepage", function () {
    var ptor;
    beforeEach(function() {
        ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    });
    it("Check visibility of elements", function() {
        //Go to homepage
        ptor.get('/#');
        //Check elements that should be visible:
        //Logo
        expect($('logo').isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();

        var logo = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id('logo'));
        expect(logo.isDisplayed()).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

One of my lines in index.html has that id, like so:

```
<div id="logo" class="title ligatures">BuddyCheck</div>
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Comment this line "expect($('logo').isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();" Do you still get the error?

Comment: If `logo` is the `id` shouldn't you add a '#'? --> `expect($('#logo').isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();`. By the way your second attempt `var logo = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id('logo')); expect(logo.isDisplayed()).toEqual(true);` should work as @Wawy pointed out and looks more 'protractor way'. ;)

Comment: Thanks both you guys! By removing the upper line it worked, stupid little error that i missed.